# Why can't I reassign a variable in a Ruby code block?

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, block

Why doesn't calling these two .map methods bring about equivalent results? The first one works as expected, whereas the second has no effect.

```
array = ["batman","boobytrap"]

puts array.map { |x| x.reverse! }
=> namtab
=> partyboob

puts array.map { |x| x = x.reverse }
=> batman
=> boobytrap
```

Comment: Could you expand your code a bit with how exactly you inspect the result(s)? (like `puts array.inspect`)

Comment: I added an answer on what I think you really wanted to ask... Would be nice to update your question though, if I am right with my assumption ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach.

The first problem is that you don't properly isolate your test cases: in your first test case you reverse the strings in the array. In your second test case you reverse them *again*. What happens if you reverse something twice? That's right: *nothing*! So, the reason why you *think* it isn't working is actually precisely the fact that it *is* working! And if it *weren't* working (i.e. not reversing the strings), then it would print the previously-reversed strings, and you would think it *does* work.

**So, lesson #1: Always isolate your test cases!**

Problem #2 is that the second piece of code doesn't do what you (probably) think it does. `x` is a local variable (because it starts with a lowercase letter). Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in, in this case the block. So, `x` only exists inside the block. You assign to it, but you never do anything with it after assigning to it. So, the assignment is actually irrelevant.

What *is* relevant, is the return value of the block. Now, in Ruby, assignments evaluate to the value that is being assigned, so considering that the assignment to `x` is superfluous, we can just get rid of it, and your code is actually exactly equivalent to this:

```
array.map { |x| x.reverse }
```

Your third problem is that the first piece also doesn't do what you (probably) think it does. [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) returns a *new* array and leaves the original array untouched, but [`String#reverse!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-reverse-21) *mutates* the strings! In other words: its primary mode of operation is a *side-effect*. In addition to the side-effect, it *also* returns the reversed string, which is another thing that confused you. It could just as well return `nil` instead to indicate that it performs a side-effect, in which case you would instead see the following:

```
array = %w[batman boobytrap]

array.map(&:reverse!)
#=> [nil, nil]

array
#=> ['namtab', 'partyboob']
```

As you can see, *if* `String#reverse!` *did* return `nil`, what you would observe is the following:

- `array.map` returns a *new* array whose elements are the return values of the block, which is just `nil`
- `array` now still contains the same `String` objects as before, but they have been mutated

Now, since `String#reverse!` actually does return the reversed `String` what you actually observe is this:

```
array = %w[batman boobytrap]

array.map(&:reverse!)
#=> ['namtab', 'partyboob']

array
#=> ['namtab', 'partyboob']

array.map(&:reverse)
#=> ['batman', 'boobytrap']

array
#=> ['namtab', 'partyboob']
```

**Which brings me to lesson #2: side-effects and shared mutable state are evil!**

You should avoid both side-effects and shared mutable state (ideally, mutable state in general, but mutable state that is shared between different pieces is especially evil) as far as possible.

Why are they evil? Well, just look at how much they confused even in this extremely simple tiny example? Can you imagine the same thing happening in a much, much larger application?

The problem with side-effects is that they "happen on the side". They are not arguments, they are not return values. You cannot print them out, inspect them, store them in a variable, place assertions on them in a unit test, and so on.

The problem with shared mutable state (mutation is just a form of side-effect, by the way) is that enables "spooky action at a distance": you have a piece of data in one place of your code, but this piece of data is shared with a different place of your code. Now, if one place mutates the data, the other place will seemingly magically have their data change out under them. In your example here, the shared state were the strings inside the array, and mutating them in one line of code made them also change in another line of code.

Comment: Awesome explanations and good point about isolating test cases!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your first map, the ! has modified the values in the original array, so it now contains reversed strings.

```
irb:001:0> array = ["batman","boobytrap"]
=> ["batman", "boobytrap"]
irb:002:0> puts array.map { |x| x.reverse! }
namtab
partyboob
=> nil
irb:003:0> array
=> ["namtab", "partyboob"]
```

So the second time is doing what you expect it to, but the entry data is not what you think it is.
If you try the second case standalone without doing the first one you will see that it works as you expect it to.

Comment: Technically, in the first map, you don't modify the array but the String objects inside the array. The result of the `map` is a new array object which references the exact same strings as he original array.

Comment: Thanks @HolgerJust, I've modified the wording

Answer (score 1):

Print `array` after `puts array.map { |x| x.reverse! }`. You will see - array has changed.
Read [documentation](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse-21) for `reverse!` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your view of what a variable is here. The variable is not the actual value, but only a reference to that value.

```
array = ["batman"]

# We are freezing this string to prevent ruby from creating a
# new object for a string with the same value.
# This isnt really necessary, just to "make sure" the memory
# address stays the same.
string = "boobytrap".freeze

array.each do |val|
  puts "before: ",
       "val.object_id: #{val.object_id}",
       "string.object_id: #{string.object_id}",
       "array[0].object_id: #{array[0].object_id}",
       ""

  val = string

  puts "after: ",
       "val.object_id: #{val.object_id}",
       "string.object_id: #{string.object_id}",
       "array[0].object_id: #{array[0].object_id}"
end

# before:
# val.object_id: 70244773377800,
# string.object_id: 70244761504360,
# array[0].object_id: 70244773377800
#
# after:
# val.object_id: 70244761504360,
# string.object_id: 70244761504360,
# array[0].object_id: 70244773377800
```

Obviously the values will differ if you run this code on your machine, but the point is, the memory address for `val` changes, while `array[0]` (which is where val comes from) stays the same after we assigned string to val. So basically what we do with the reassignment is, we tell ruby the value for val is no longer found in 70244773377800, but in 70244761504360. The array still refers to its first value with 70244773377800 though!

The `#reverse!` method call you use in your example on x on the other hand changes the value of whatever is found at 70244773377800 in memory, which is why it works as you expected.

TLDR;
Your first example changes the value in memory, while the second example assigns a new memory address to a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `array.map { |x| x.reverse! }`, it changed the array values.

```
array = ["batman","boobytrap"]

puts array.map { |x| x.reverse! }
=> namtab
=> partyboob

array
=> ["namtab", "partyboob"]
```

If you perform second operation on the same array, it will produce the same results as you have stated in the question. However, it will not change the value of original array.

```
array = ["batman","boobytrap"]

puts array.map { |x| x.reverse! }
=> namtab
=> partyboob

array
=> ["namtab", "partyboob"]

puts array.map { |x| x = x.reverse }
=> batman
=> boobytrap

array
=> ["namtab", "partyboob"]
```

To change the value of original array, use `map!` in second operation.

```
array = ["batman","boobytrap"]

puts array.map { |x| x.reverse! }
=> namtab
=> partyboob

array
=> ["namtab", "partyboob"]

puts array.map! { |x| x.reverse }
=> batman
=> boobytrap

array
=> ["batman", "boobytrap"]
```